# display instructions if mixed content is not allowed

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

Is there any way to detect that a users browser hasn't enabled the Allow mixed content feature?

What i want is that if it isn't enabled, the div where the http-iframe should otherwise load displays some text telling the user what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx

I assume that you own the secure site? if so you should consider proxying the insecure content.

anyway you could reference an image/script from the source handle errors on the "onload" event. that should do the trick.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with handle errors.. You mean the Onload event of the iframe? It will fire that event regardless of content displayed/not. Examining the content to see if the body-tag is empty is not possible i know. Proxying the content could be a solution but leaves the server with much more to do and i preferably don't want that...